# how to fetch the id of name that has been stored in another model and using the id of name in storing values in pivot table database in laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, controller, pivot-table, laravel-8

I am facing an error.
so error is like , I have three tables users,roles and users_roles tables , and users_roles is pivot table between both . the role contains Admin,Userand editor .
now all the users have been created , roles have been created .
now for users_roles table:
my migration for user_roles table is like:

```
      Schema::create('users_roles', function (Blueprint $table) {

        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        
        $table->id();
        
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('role_id');
            
        
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles');
        
    });
```

now the thing is that. I have to assign a role to each user , in my table(on browser) where all my users are present and their consist of add assign role button which redirects to add role to users
their is form ,where it can select role to user and for retriving the roles ,I am fetching from the role model and showing it there.
and the blade file is something like this:

```
          @foreach ($Role as $role)
            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="role" value="{{$role->name}}">
                <label class="form-check-label">{{$role->name}}</label>
            </div>    
          @endforeach
```

and the each role contains an id attach to it , say 1 for admin ,2 for user and 3 for editor .
now the main question is that if user selects user then , it have the id of 2 which is assigned in role model ..
now how to save the id of user(role) into the RoleUser model , because here we will get the name of that role.. how to link two tables and store the two id in role_user--

here is the store function of role_user method:

```
 class RoleAssignController extends Controller 
{

     public function store($user_id,Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->all();
    $User_id = $request->route('user_id');
    // dd($User_id);
    
    // dd($data);
    $rules = array(
        'role' => 'required',
    );
    $validate = Validator::make($data,$rules);  
    if ($validate->fails()) {
        return redirect()->back()->withInput()->withErrors($validate);
    }
    else{
   
        $form_data = array(
            'user_id' => $User_id,
            'role_id' => 
        );

        $UserRole = UserRole::create($form_data);
        
        return redirect('/Admin/user')->with('success');
    }       
}

}
```

this store method is of assignrolecontroller which is controller of pivot table (role_user) ???
what will be stored in role_id column and how to do that ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should probably follow the framework's conventions when naming your tables, so the pivot table should be named `role_user` (singular case, alphabetically ordered)

Then you should make sure to define the (ManyToMany) relationship between the `User` and the `Role` model.

in `app\Models\User.php` make sure you have this function:

```php
    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
    }
```

in `app\Models\Role.php` make sure you have this function:

```php
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }
```

**Note: If you don't rename the pivot table you must provide a second parameter with the name of the pivot table, eq:**

```php
return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class, 'users_roles');
```

Finally, in your controller (store method) you should just do something like:

```php
$user = User::find($user_id);
$roles = $request->input('roles');
$user->roles()->sync($roles); // where roles is the array you get from the request
```

One more thing to note here:
If you would only need your users to have one role at a time (as per your example with radio buttons) then your relationship should probably not even contain a pivot table in the first place; you could just store the `role_id` in the `users` table.

If you would like to design your database for a user to have multiple roles, then you should change the radio boxes to checkboxes and the name of the input from "role" to "roles[]" as well.

For more information please take a look at the official documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#syncing-associations

Comment: thanks, I think you just misunderstood the question .. let me update my question

Comment: hey there.. I just updated the question, this store method is of  role_user not user , so how to do that now???

Comment: and I have added relationship between them earlier only , not want to make question so long..  so how to fetch from role model..

Comment: You mentioned that you have one `RoleUser` model. Is that extending the `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;` class? If that's the path you want to take, that's also possible but you should change also the `User` and `Role` classes accordingly. And it's way too much overengineering for your use case!

Comment: then what is the best method to that?? I have not use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot; in RoleUser

Comment: So, basically, if you just want one role for each user you should get rid of the pivot table altogether and just add a `role_id` foreign field to the `users` table.

Comment: But if you want a user to have multiple roles, I basically wrote all the code and gave you all info needed.